# Prevent call to function from URL but allow internally

Tags: php, function

I have a controller which have a function test(). I want to make this function inaccessible when access by the URL and I can't make private or protected because I want the same function to used by other controllers.

How can I achieve this, any suggestions?

Comment: A controller should redirect to other controller, not call each other.

Comment: make a `$_SESSION` variable, if the user enters from a URL then make it `1`, and just check if `$_SESSION['check']=1` `exit();`

Answer (score 1):

If the function file is brought in by `include` or `require` functions to the controller file then you could have something like this at the start of your function file:

```
defined("CONTROLLER") or die();
```

Then, before the `include` function calls the function file in, use:

```
define("CONTROLLER", true);
```

That way, the function file is killed by the `die()` command when accessed directly but runs as normal on any page you specifically included it in.